# Chrome extension re-executes the code on main popup.html each time after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to count the number of times a URL is hit by the user.

Most of the state is maintained on the server.

But when I take the URL as input from the user and make an ajax call to get the corresponding count, it RE-EXECUTES the whole script. Basically over writing the whole data on the body by getting the data by re-executing  sendPageOpen() function. It writes the data momentarily by the ajax call but then replaces everything as it is essentially re-executed.

If I send more messages from the server, it listens and appends to the body(and do not re-execute), but re-executes the whole code each time after the ajax call.

Although I want the data using sendPageOpen() socket listener each time the popup is re opened, but I do not want it re-execute the whole code just after making the ajax call.

Please ignore my repetition of the work re-execute so many times. I am pulling my hair.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

var url = ""; 



    chrome.tabs.query({"active":true}, function(data){
    //alert("why");
    console.log(data[0].url);
    currentURL = data[0].url;
    sendPageOpen(url);
 });



$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );


$('form').submit(function(){
    debugger;
    console.log("Running");
    var myurl = {'url' : currentURL,
                'msg' : $('#msg').val()
                }
    socket.emit('get URL', JSON.stringify(myurl));

    $('#body').append($('<li>').text($('#msg').val()));


    socket.on(currentURL, function(msg){
    // console.log(msg);

    $('#body').append($('<li>').text($('#msg').val()));


    });

});


});



function sendPageOpen(url){
// debugger;
  var page = {'url' : url
                };

  socket.emit('pageopen', JSON.stringify(page));


  socket.on(currentURL, function(msg){


  $('#body').append($('<li>').text(msg));


  });
// return false;
});
```

Comment: Missing `event.preventDefault();` in `$('form').submit` callback?

Comment: Cool, thanks. After working with the uber cool JS frameworks, I was taking jquery for granted.